# Class frequency comparison (exponential distribution)

Tags: chi-squared-test, distance, exponential-distribution, frequency

I have two different sources of data and I would like to check if their class distributions are similar and how much.

The first dataset ($D_1$) has 2M samples and the second ($D_2$) 6M.

When I calculate counts per class, they have exponential distribution - many rare classes and a small number of very frequent ones.

I would like to do the comparison twice based on 2 variables. In the first case there are 100 classes and in the second 5500.

I am thinking about using chi-square (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) or G-test. However, they should be used with a normal distribution. Thus, I wonder if I can use *log1p* transformation or not.

Another idea which I have is calculating KL distance between the class frequencies and the distance to uniform distribution to have a reference.

Despite the mentioned tests, I am interested in what is a correct approach to compare the class distribution in the mentioned situation.

**EDIT** (in reply to *whuber* comment):

Yes, I mean here the discrete values. The raw data are like labels e.g. [A, A, B, A, C, C]. Then I transformed it to counts: {A: 3, B: 1, C: 2}. By exponential, I meant that when I check the number of samples for each class, the histogram looks like:
[image: Class size distribution]

Comment: Could you clarify for us what a "class distribution" is and in what sense *counts* (which by their very nature take on discrete values) can be considered to have "exponential distribution," which usually refers to a specific family of *continuous* distributions?

Comment: Your plot looks more skew than an exponential distribution.